# Hide an element when clicking anywhere outside it with pure css

Tags: css

Searching I can only find javascript/jquery solutions, isn't there any way to do it purely with css?

```
#UserMenu.block { 
display: block; 
}

#UserMenu {
font-size: 16px;
padding: 15px;
display: none;
background: #333;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
width: 200px;
}


#UserMenu a {
color: #24A9D8;
display: block;
position: relative;
padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

You can test it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hLch3jku/

Comment: You're using JavaScript to show the element; why not use it to hide it?

Comment: There is no way. You need to use JS for it because it's an event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkbox for trick. Put a label and checkbox in it. Put your other elements. And when checkbox is checked hide your elements with css. But this is a cheap trick, better use javascript.